# Could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[List[List[Int]]]

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

In postgres I am trying to map column of type integer[][] using slick 3.2

When trying to define below

```
def bbox = column[List[List[Int]]]("bbox")
```

I get the following error

```
Could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[List[List[Int]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg)

```
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._

trait MyPostgresProfile extends ExPostgresProfile
  with PgArraySupport
  with PgDate2Support
  with PgRangeSupport
  with PgHStoreSupport
//with PgPlayJsonSupport
  with PgSearchSupport
//with PgPostGISSupport
  with PgNetSupport
  with PgLTreeSupport {
  def pgjson = "jsonb" // jsonb support is in postgres 9.4.0 onward; for 9.3.x use "json"

// Add back `capabilities.insertOrUpdate` to enable native `upsert` support; for postgres 9.5+
//override protected def computeCapabilities: Set[Capability] =
//  super.computeCapabilities + JdbcProfile.capabilities.insertOrUpdate

  override val api = MyAPI

  object MyAPI extends API with ArrayImplicits
    with DateTimeImplicits
//  with JsonImplicits
    with NetImplicits
    with LTreeImplicits
    with RangeImplicits
    with HStoreImplicits
    with SearchImplicits
    with SearchAssistants {
    implicit val intListTypeMapper = new SimpleArrayJdbcType[Int]("integer").to(_.toList)
    implicit val intListListTypeMapper = new AdvancedArrayJdbcType[List[Int]]("integer[]",
      utils.SimpleArrayUtils.fromString[List[Int]](s => 
        scala.util.Try(s.substring(5, s.length - 1).split(",").map(_.trim.toInt).toList).getOrElse(List())
      )(_).orNull,
      utils.SimpleArrayUtils.mkString[List[Int]](_.toString)
    ).to(_.toList)
  }
}

object MyPostgresProfile extends MyPostgresProfile

import MyPostgresProfile.api._

case class Something(name: String, bbox: List[List[Int]])

class SomethingTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Something](tag, "Something") {
  def name = column[String]("name", O.PrimaryKey)
  def bbox = column[List[List[Int]]]("bbox")

  def * = (name, bbox) <> (Something.tupled, Something.unapply)
}

val query = TableQuery[SomethingTable]
```

In `build.sbt` one should add

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg" % "0.16.2"
```

Comment: scala.util.Try(s.substring(1, s.length - 1).split(",").map(_.trim.toInt).toList).getOrElse(List())

Comment: "List(" are first 5 characters, ")" is the last character.

Comment: Why are we doing substring from 5th character instead of first?

Comment: Because first 5 characters are "List(".

Comment: Found slickpg already implements it like this.                                               
implicit val intintWitness = ElemWitness.AnyWitness.asInstanceOf[ElemWitness[List[Int]]]
    implicit val simpleIntIntListTypeMapper = new SimpleArrayJdbcType[List[Int]]("int[]")
      .to(_.asInstanceOf[Seq[Array[Any]]].toList.map(_.toList.asInstanceOf[List[Int]]))

Comment: I want to support pg integer[] type, but it never worked for me using slick-pg. Unfortunately I had to store the values as string (Comma separated) and apply separate logic to split it using comma delimiter to get List[Int]